# How to set video capture format in opencv using python?

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have a webcam which supports YUYV (raw) and MJPEG (compressed) formats. When I capture video stream - `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`, openCV takes YUYV as default.

I want to use MJPEG (MJPG). I found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html?highlight=videocapture#cv2.VideoCapture.set) that it is possible. I try to set it by command: `cap.set(7, ('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))`, but it doesn't work. How can I choose which video format I want to get in OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below line.

```
cap.set(8, ('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
```